# How can i set an unbreakable password on py PC?

Tags: privacy

I want to set an unbreakable password for windows 7 on my personal computer because my friends mostly guess my password. When they are failed to guess my password they break  it with an technique. I want to get rid off this all. I often try to change windows 8 and 10, but they reset all my settings and i loose my privacy. My computer contains my personal data like family pics so i want to them private. My friend break my password and after this they tell me about my personal data that what kind of pic, videos, and documents i have. Me and my friends are room mates. It can be another one who breaks my password for my room mates. My laptop is secured because i have an fingerprint privacy on my laptop but any type of password on windows is easy to breakable for my room mates which not secured for me.

Comment: It seems to me that you should upgrade your friends, or at least deny them physical access to your computer.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question, unless you provide more details. The strength of the password is likely to be totally irrelevant here. If you keep being "hacked" by your friends, you need to tell us what they are doing exactly, and the whole scenario. For example, if they have physical access to your computer and they are knowledgeable enough, the strength of your password is irrelevant and the solution to your problem is totally different.

Comment: All respect able members i often keeps the length of my password upto 20 which contains symbols, numbers and alphabets. But its is difficult to break so how they do so.

Comment: You need to edit your answer and add as many details as you can about the whole situation, for example: how do you find out you have been hacked? How do you know it was your friends? Can your friends physically access your computer while you are away? What do you do to fix the hack and restore your computer to a safe state? Etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remember, depending on your jurisdiction, your friends may be breaking the law.

There are a couple of really neat techniques to create near-unguessable passwords.

The first is online tools: just Google "strong password generator". For your needs, 8 characters should suffice. They should be generated randomly. If you can remember a phone number (typically 11 characters in the UK) you can remember 8.

The second is to pick four words at random, and then a capitalisation strategy of your choice. resilientHORSEBATTERYstaple would do.

A third technique is to use an equation. FIVEtimes5=25 or 5*five=TWENTYFIVE! would keep you safe.

However, a Windows password alone won't keep you safe if your friends are able to boot using a Live CD. This may be a bit advanced for you, but consider using an Encrypted Windows install next time you install Windows, or putting a password on your Bios. The Bios password is hard to do, and if you mess up you can break a lot of things, so just go with the above strategies as a first attempt.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is terrible advice. Most of this is just homebrew schemes which can be trivially guessed by a Hashcat ruleset (an equation? Really?), and the rest is outdated advice (4 words is _not_ enough).